# Is there a way to continue focusing a MathQuill input when a button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, mathquill

I’m using the [Desmos fork for MathQuill](https://github.com/desmosinc/mathquill) with buttons to input symbols:

```js
var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2);
var answerSpan = document.getElementById("input");
var answerMathField = MQ.MathField(answerSpan);
document.getElementById("keypad-left-parenthesis").onclick = function () {
  answerMathField.focus();
  answerMathField.cmd("(");
};
document.getElementById("keypad-right-parenthesis").onclick = function () {
  answerMathField.focus();
  answerMathField.cmd(")");
};
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 1em;
}
.mq-editable-field {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
button {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathquill@0.10.1-a/build/mathquill.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="input"></div>
<div><button id="keypad-left-parenthesis">(</button><button id="keypad-right-parenthesis">)</button></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathquill@0.10.1-a/build/mathquill.min.js"></script>
```

*(There isn’t a CDN I can use for the Desmos fork, but this behavior exists for both versions of MathQuill)*

When I press the left parenthesis symbol on desktop, the math field temporarily loses focus, then the left parenthesis is inserted. A right parenthesis approaches as a “ghost”. But when I press the right parenthesis symbol, the math field loses focus again, the “ghost” becomes solid, and thus the right parenthesis is inserted inside, producing two groups of parentheses—one inside another—when only one was intended.

Is there a way to apply the focus style even when the button is being clicked, like [the Desmos website does](https://www.desmos.com/fourfunction)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) event you're using can't prevent the focus loss.

One way to fix the issue is to use the [`onmousedown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onmousedown) instead of the [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

This should not change the behaviour but allows us to use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to keep the focus on the input

---

So the button would look like:

```js
document.getElementById("keypad-left-parenthesis").onmousedown = function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    answerMathField.cmd("(");
};
```

---

Updated snippet:

```js
var MQ = MathQuill.getInterface(2);
var answerSpan = document.getElementById("input");
var answerMathField = MQ.MathField(answerSpan);

document.getElementById("keypad-left-parenthesis").onmousedown = function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  answerMathField.cmd("(");
};
document.getElementById("keypad-right-parenthesis").onmousedown = function () {
  event.preventDefault();
  answerMathField.cmd(")");
};
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 1em;
}
.mq-editable-field {
  margin: 1em 0;
}
button {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathquill@0.10.1-a/build/mathquill.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="input"></div>
<div><button id="keypad-left-parenthesis">(</button><button id="keypad-right-parenthesis">)</button></div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathquill@0.10.1-a/build/mathquill.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The version in Desmos only inserts `(` on mouseup (I guess it uses a click event for inserting the command), and if the text field is not yet focused, it moves the focus there. But I think it should be simple to change it.

Comment: You could try to use onmouseup, should be the same idea.

Comment: No problem—this would work. Thanks!